# SSRS URL Parameter won't set

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

I have the following c# code in a web form:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url;
            string startdate;
            string enddate;
            string costcenter;
            string account;

            //url = "http://server/reportserver?/Finance/Cost Spending/Cost Center Details&rs:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=false";
            url = "http://server/reportserver?/Finance/Cost Spending/Cost Center Totals&rs:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=false";
            costcenter = "&costcenter=990";

            startdate="&startdate=" + Convert.ToString(txtStartDate.Text);
            enddate = "&enddate=" + Convert.ToString(txtEndDate.Text);

            account="&account=" + Convert.ToString(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);

            url =url + startdate + enddate + costcenter + account;


            //TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
                Response.Redirect(url, false);

        }
```

I've tested a very similer version of this code against another report, the only different being the costcenter parameter.  The other report worked fine, but every time i run this code i get the error: "the 'costcenter' parameter is missing a value".  The only thing i can think of that's significantly different between the two reports is that in the Cost Center Totals report the costcenter parameter is used to populate the accounts parameter (both are multi-select).

Here's what the parameters page looks like:
[image: parameters]

Comment: sigh, i guess no-one on here knows....

Comment: What version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: Just a wild guess, is Parameter=false in the url string causing this behaviour by any chance?

Comment: Parameters=false doesn't do anything except hide the parameter options from the HTML Viewer.  However, it would be interesting to know if the  options are being set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the issue thanks to Alison's poke at the parameters/data sets.  What was happening was I had 4 parameters, start date, end date, cost center, and accounts.  In the report the account data set relies on the cost center parameters to populate the drop down list.  I created a copy of the report, removed the cost center parameter, and removed the data set from the account parameter.  I updated the code and ran it and BAM!  It worked.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using multiple datasets in your report?  If so, try setting the datasets to execute serially:

1. Open the data source dialog in report designer
2. Select the "Use Single Transaction" checkbox

Some other troubleshooting steps you can try:

- Try removing the Report Server Command "&rs:Command=Render" from the query string and see what happens.
- Also, if you change the Viewer Command to true, are you able to at least see that the parameters are populated properly (ie: "&rc:Parameters=true"?

Comment: i don't know what data source dialog you're talking about.  Also, the project is in vs 2010, but the report is SSRS 2005.

Answer (score 1):

I've been under the impression that one difference between running a report on the web server and running it in code is that in code it does not bother with the "Available Values" queries for parameters. In code, you aren't selecting a human-readable label from a drop-down which then passes in the corresponding value. Instead, you just provide the value to the parameter.

So, have you tried not specifying the cost center parameter at all? If the account parameter is all the report's recordsets really are based on, then it may be superfluous to set it.

**Update:**

Since the time I wrote this answer originally I've learned that dependent parameters (at least in SSRS 2008) must be *after* the parameter(s) they're dependent on. Make sure your parameters are ordered in a sensible way.

It looks like that's what you've done, I just wanted to mention the possibility.

Comment: Yes, i get the same error.  "The 'costcenter' parameter is missing a value "

Answer (score 1):

Check that the Costcenter 990 is in your database!

I did some testing. I have a table "Person" with 4 rows and a PersonID 1 to 4. If set &PersonID=5 for a required single value parameter with "&rc:Parameters=true" then I get a drop-down box so I can choose one of the 4 valid persons.

If I set &PersonID=5 with "&rc:Parameters=false" then I get the message "the PersonID parameter is missing a value".

Comment: 990 exists, it's the primary value i've been testing the report and stored procedures with.

Comment: What do you have for "Available Values" for the costcenter parameter? It looks to me like 990 isn't one of the available values. Remember that it is the Value field that will be compared against, not the Label field. Is 990 an ID, or the name of the costcenter? If it is the ID, it is better to make the Parameter an integer. If that doesn't help, try hacking some values for the costcenter parameter into your browser URL bar until the report shows!

Comment: To check the Available Values you either need to look at the report code, or do what Alison suggests and set rc:Parameters=true.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar kind of issue. Removing the parameter dependency made it work. I had parameter B depending on parameter A. It worked perfectly when you access the report server directly. But when I tried to bind it programmatically to the report viewer control, even after supplying the parameter using `ReportParameter` and adding to Parameters list, it was merely saying that "The 'Parameter B' is missing".

So, I went back to the report server. Redeployed the report by removing parameter dependency. It worked. :-)

Comment: awesome!  did you figure that out from here or messing about with it yourself?